# AutoCAD: Help with exporting micrometer details to PDF

Tags: autocad, photonics

I'm using AutoCAD and am trying to export a photolithography mask to a PDF file so it can be viewed and shown to others outside of the AutoCAD program. I'm having trouble with this, as whenever I export it to PDF, small details don't come out in the PDF file. These micrometer-scale details are blurred and the lines are too thick in the exported PDF. I'm very new to AutoCAD, so I would appreciate all the help and tips I can get!

Comment: look at you  line weights too.  if you have things drawn to scale, then you need to scale them up sufficiently and use appropriate line colours/weight.  You don't want your drawn line to be thicker than the space between your lines type deal.

Answer (score 0):

So do a crop of the screen zoomed as needed.

Sometimes a general view and one or two detail views do help the explanation.

Once you have those they can be made into a pdf or a relevant image format.